# error with my img src using react, photo is not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, src

I keep having difficulty trying to render out images onto my site. I've tried several ways to return my img src such as:

```
    1. <img src={require('../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage)} 
alt="Post Image"/>
    2. <img src={require(`../../blogPostImages/${post.blogImage}`)} alt="Post Image" />
    3.<img src={'../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage'} />
```

I had a similar issue before, and I imported the image at the top of the file and it worked. I tried doing the same thing this time and it's not working. This is what I am trying to import:
import Img from '../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage;
and returning the import as:

I feel like I my directory is correct, I am currently in my blogPost>index.js trying to access my blogPostImages. Thanks for the help in advanced!
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50z5P.png)
[Broken image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oezSQ.png)

Comment: returning the import as* : <img src={Img} alt="Post Image" />

Comment: It should always work. Try this..Instead of  ***<img src={require(`../../blogPostImages/${post.blogImage}`)} alt="Post Image" />*** try to use ***<img src={require(`..path to image`)} alt="Post Image" />`*** If it works then you are having issues in path.

Comment: @rahulkumar just tried <img src={require(..path to image)} alt="Post Image" /> but didn't work there was a syntax error with the ..path to image

Comment: That means your path is incorrect.

Comment: Try log it on the console `../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage` and see if it matches to your path